# Keying multiple emptys which are IK targets results in location reverting to 0 when timeline is moved

Tags: animation, rigging, inverse-kinematics, graph-editor, actions

I've run into a very strange issue with my otherwise normal skeleton and IK rig. When I key my IK emptys, every IK empty snaps to the most recent location keyed when I pan through the timeline. This has rendered my rig unusable, and I can't figure out what is causing this. My Blend file is available here.

I'd love to know what I'm doing wrong and if there is something I shouldn't be doing. I was under the assumption this was typical for working with IK rigs?

[Blend File Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bjSVJo2zlpR4E0c7F0WVo-Vj4pxjBY5X/view?usp=sharing)

Edit: Some people are confused by what I mean by this. If you open the blend file and start keying the IK handles it should be immediately apparent.

I've got 7 emptys. If I key 7 of them at a different pose, this works correctly, until I pan the timeline. As soon as I move from say, keyed frame 1, to unkeyed frame 2, the first 6 keyed emptys snap to the position of the 7th empty, all overlapping the same location. This makes it so I cannot key the emptys or animate my model with the IK handles or poles.This issue also occurs if I save or reload the file.

Comment: maybe i didn't understand you right, but this is "normal" behaviour. If you keyframe a value at 0(or any other frame and this is your only keyframe) this value will be take for every frame after it until you set a new keyframe. Or you delete the keyframe.

Comment: I've added more information. The issue is the keys aren't correctly evaluated for each empty individually. I believe this isn't a bug, but rather something to do with how the blend file has been set up.

Comment: The issue is that all of your empties have linked animations.  When you animate one, you animate all (although this doesn't show up until changing frames.)  You need to select all of your empties and use the "make single user" operation to unlink their object animation data.